Calculator GUI Prints Only "2" Regardless of Calculation – C Backend and Python (Tkinter) Frontend
Hello everyone,
I'm new to programming and recently built a calculator application with a backend written in C and a frontend using Python's Tkinter. When I run main.py, the GUI appears without any issues, but no matter what calculations I perform, the output is always "2." I'm unsure why this happens.
I’ve provided the GitHub link to my project below. Any insights into why this might be occurring or guidance on fixing it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your help!
github link : github link
I expected the calculator to perform arithmetic operations correctly, but it keeps outputting "2" regardless of the input

Don't make us click on an external link to see your code.  Post the code directly in the question.  If it's too long, then make a shorter version of it, removing anything that isn't central to your question.

Hi Fyodor, welcome, in order for you to get help, I suggest you edit your question, and add your code as text.

The build instructions in the README.md don't work. How do you build libcalculations.so?

i used : gcc -shared -o libcalculations.so -fPIC calculations.c to build libcalculations.so

According to this you need to set the return types of the library functions because they are assumed to return int.

Debug mode can help you. In function perform_operation send true values "a" and  "b", but your problem in string:
        return operations[operation](ctypes.c_double(a), ctypes.c_double(b))

add next code:
lib = ctypes.CDLL(os.path.join(".", "libcalculations.so"))
lib.add.restype = ctypes.c_double
lib.subtract.restype = ctypes.c_double
lib.multiply.restype = ctypes.c_double
lib.divide.restype = ctypes.c_double

